# Qt3D - Instance rendering of 2 squares. PrimitiveType? InstanceCount?

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d, geometry-instancing

I'd like to display on the screen 2 squares using instance rendering.
The problem is :
When I draw 2 squares, they are connected. I can't draw multiple separate square. 
I know it has to do with PrimitiveType : i'm using *Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::LineLoop* or *Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::TriangleFan* but is there a way to tell Qt to separate my data buffer in multiple instances ? so that the PrimitiveType apply on each instances and not all the vertices.

I got a function that create shapes :

```
Qt3DCore::QEntity* SceneBuilder::createShapeInstancing(const QList<QVector3D> & listVertices, int nbPointGeometry, const QColor color, Qt3DCore::QEntity * rootEntity) 
{
    // Material
    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *material = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(rootEntity);
    material->setAmbient(color);

    // Custom entity
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *customMeshEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);

    // Custom Mesh
    Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer *customMeshRenderer = new Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer(rootEntity);
    Qt3DRender::QGeometry *customGeometry = new Qt3DRender::QGeometry(customMeshRenderer);

    Qt3DRender::QBuffer *vertexDataBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(Qt3DRender::QBuffer::VertexBuffer, customGeometry);

    int nbPointGeometry = nbPoint;

    QByteArray vertexBufferData;
    vertexBufferData.resize(listVertices.size() * nbPointGeometry * sizeof(QVector3D));
    QVector3D *posData = reinterpret_cast<QVector3D *>(vertexBufferData.data());

    QList<QVector3D>::const_iterator it;
    for (it = listVertices.begin(); it != listVertices.end(); it++)
    {
        *posData = *it;
        ++posData;
    }

    vertexDataBuffer->setData(vertexBufferData);

    //Attributes

    Qt3DRender::QAttribute *positionAttribute = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute();
    positionAttribute->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());
    positionAttribute->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    positionAttribute->setBuffer(vertexDataBuffer);
    positionAttribute->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float);
    positionAttribute->setVertexSize(3);
    positionAttribute->setByteOffset(0);
    positionAttribute->setByteStride((0 + 3) * sizeof(float));
    positionAttribute->setCount(listVertices.size());
    //positionAttribute->setDivisor(1);

    customGeometry->addAttribute(positionAttribute);

    customMeshRenderer->setGeometry(customGeometry);
    //customMeshRenderer->setInstanceCount(listVertices.size()/nbPoint);
    if (nbPointGeometry == 1)
        customMeshRenderer->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Points);
    else if (nbPointGeometry == 2)
        customMeshRenderer->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Lines);
    else if (nbPointGeometry == 3)
        customMeshRenderer->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Triangles);
    else
        customMeshRenderer->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::LineLoop);

    customMeshEntity->addComponent(customMeshRenderer);
    customMeshEntity->addComponent(material);

    return customMeshEntity;
}
```

When i call this function, i put my 2 squares inside the listVertices variables. So that all my squares are display in one draw call.

But the shapes are one way or another connected. Is there a way to remove that ? I'm not using **InstanceCount** or **Divisor** but i don't know how it works. I made some tests with it but nothing worked

Comment: Why don't you simply call the function twice and have two separate entities? That should disconnect them.

Comment: Here i just simplified the example.
In fact i've got hundreds of thousands of squares. 
Create an entity for each square is too heavy for Qt3D. That's why i'd like to use instance rendering

Comment: According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-overview.html#instanced-rendering), instanced rendering is not yet implemented. Have you tried adding your hundreds of thousands of squares? I'm assuming that it kills your computer but you could give `QFrustumCulling` a shot. Other than that I'm not sure if there's a solution for you problem in Qt3D.

Comment: Well, couldn't you use `Lines` instead of `LineLoop` for more than 3 points, too? Then of course you would have to add another set of points for the closing line. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes Florian, indeed that's a solution (despite the fact that it will be quite annoying when i will implement movement to my squares).
However it's still annoying because at the end of my project i'd like to render a surface on the square => what i did with PrimitiveType::TriangleFan ...
And if i'm not mistaken it's impossible to add it later ? (i mean without a PrimitiveType set at TriangleFan)

Comment: Otherwise i can cut all my polygons in triangles and set primitive type as Triangle

Comment: I think `TriangleFan` and `LineLoop` are intended to work the way they do, i.e. connect everything. I guess your best shot is to use `Triangle` (until Qt3D supports instanced rendering).

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your time i will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I just found an example of instanced rendering [here](https://github.com/wonder-sk/qt3d-experiments).

They subclassed `QSphereGeometry` and performed the instanced rendering in a shader. You could create a `RectangleGeometry` which holds the vertices for one triangle and equip it with the same functionality as the `InstancedGeometry` in the example.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Well, i understand how it works, thank's for pointing me out this solution.
But there is still a problem for me because i'd like to be able to pick element. But using shader it's impossible. In fact, picking element (with for exemple 10 triangles created with the code i've provide) is not implemented with Qt. But I think it's more likely possible to implement it

Comment: Well, I still feel like my answer answered your question because you didn't say anything about picking. You could ask a new question regarding your picking issue I don't think we should discuss this in the comments.

Comment: I experimented a bit and got to a solution by rendering the scene with IDs as colors. If you post the question regarding this issue I could post this as an answer (although I don't know if it will be sufficient for you).

Comment: Well thank you for experimenting. I manage to implement picking. I'm using the first solution of "instance rendering" wich is to cut all my shapes in triangles and inside the vertexes position buffer i added an id to located wich shape was picked

Comment: Cool, glad to hear you managed to implement it! I did it using the instanced rendering answer that I provided and implemented picking the same way as you did. Although I only managed to use IDs for 65k objects (3 bytes) so I'm not sure if that is enough for you. Would you care to post another question regarding this issue and provide your solution as an answer? I'd be interested to see details!

Comment: Oh and obviously post the way you implemented instanced rendering as an answer to your question here!